# Scrapy spider for Tripadvisor Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min)

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape reviews for all hotels in Punta Cana. The code seems to run but when I call crawl, it doesn't actually crawl any of the sites. Here are my file structures, what I called, and what happened when I ran it.

folder structure:

```
├── scrapy.cfg
└── tripadvisor_reviews
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── items.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── items.py
    ├── middlewares.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
        │   └── tripadvisorSpider.cpython-37.pyc
        └── tripadvisorSpider.py
```

tripadvisorSpider.py

```py
import scrapy
from tripadvisor_reviews.items import TripadvisorReviewsItem


class tripadvisorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tripadvisorspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.tripadvisor.com"]

    def start_requests(self):

        urls = [
            'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html'
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="listing_title"]/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotel)

        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse_hotel(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="hotels-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText"]/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_review)

        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_hotel)

    def parse_review(self, response):
        item = TripadvisorReviewsItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath(
            '//div[@class="hotels-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText"]/text()').extract()
        item['content'] = response.xpath(
            '//q[@class="hotels-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText"]/text()').extract()
        # item['stars'] = response.xpath(
        #     '//span[@class="rate sprite-rating_s rating_s"]/img/@alt').extract()[0]
        print(item)
        yield item
```

items.py

```py
import scrapy


class TripadvisorReviewsItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    title = scrapy.Field()
    content = scrapy.Field()
    # stars = scrapy.Field()
```

I ran it using the following command in terminal:

```
scrapy crawl tripadvisorspider -o items.json
```

This is my terminal output

```
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.2 started (bot: tripadvisor_reviews)
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) - [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform Darwin-18.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tripadvisor_reviews', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tripadvisor_reviews.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tripadvisor_reviews.spiders']}
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: aae78556d6b8c59b
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-05-14 12:32:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-05-14 12:32:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-05-14 12:32:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html> (referer: None)
2019-05-14 12:32:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d15025732-Reviews-Impressive_Resort_Spa_Punta_Cana-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d313884-Reviews-Punta_Cana_Princess_All_Suites_Resort_Spa-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dom.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d4451011-Reviews-The_Westin_Puntacana_Resort_Club-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d10175054-Reviews-Secrets_Cap_Cana_Resort_Spa-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d7307251-Reviews-The_Level_at_Melia_Caribe_Beach-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Re.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d292158-Reviews-Grand_Palladium_Punta_Cana_Resort_Spa-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Repub.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d1604057-Reviews-Secrets_Royal_Beach_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d649099-Reviews-Zoetry_Agua_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d150842-Reviews-Iberostar_Dominicana_Hotel-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d15515013-Reviews-Grand_Memories_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d150841-Reviews-Iberostar_Selection_Bavaro-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d1233228-Reviews-Iberostar_Grand_Bavaro-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d149397-Reviews-Bavaro_Princess_Resort_Spa_Casino-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d584407-Reviews-Ocean_Blue_Sand-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d259337-Reviews-Grand_Palladium_Bavaro_Suites_Resort_Spa-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Domi.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d150854-Reviews-Hotel_Riu_Palace_Macao-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d11701188-Reviews-BlueBay_Grand_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d14838260-Reviews-Melia_Punta_Cana_Beach_Resort-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d1595124-Reviews-Luxury_Bahia_Principe_Esmeralda-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d508162-Reviews-Dreams_Punta_Cana_Resort_Spa-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d1076311-Reviews-Hard_Rock_Hotel_Casino_Punta_Cana-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d10595200-Reviews-Grand_Bahia_Principe_Aquamarine-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d611114-Reviews-Hotel_Riu_Palace_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3200043-d8709413-Reviews-Excellence_El_Carmen-Uvero_Alto_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d1199681-Reviews-Luxury_Bahia_Principe_Ambar-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d1889895-Reviews-Karibo_Punta_Cana-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d6454132-Reviews-Premium_Level_at_Barcelo_Bavaro_Palace-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Domin.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d15080584-Reviews-Impressive_Premium_Resorts_Spa-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Re.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g147293-d2687221-Reviews-NH_Punta_Cana-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g3176298-d579774-Reviews-Iberostar_Punta_Cana-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic.html> (referer: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g147293-Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Province_Dominican_Republic-Hotels.html)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 46023,
 'downloader/request_count': 32,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 32,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5599418,
 'downloader/response_count': 32,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 32,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 19, 32, 21, 637712),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 33,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'memusage/max': 51412992,
 'memusage/startup': 51412992,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 32,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 31,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 31,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 31,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 31,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 14, 19, 32, 12, 996979)}
2019-05-14 12:32:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector is not working:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="hotels-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText"]/a/@href')
```

The element on the site is `<a>` and not `<div>`, also the class name seems wrong. Perhaps this site append some random data to the class name, as you can see below

```
<a href="/ShowUserReviews-g3176298-d259337-r673990694-Grand_Palladium_Bavaro_Suites_Resort_Spa-Bavaro_Punta_Cana_La_Altagracia_Provinc.html" class="hotels-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText--3QrTy"><span><span>Ótima experiência! Resort amplo, com diversas opções de entretenimento!!!</span></span></a>
```

You can try to match only part of the string, for example:

```
//a[contains(@class, "hotels-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText")]
```

Comment: yeah I guess I was looking for exact match on that. That fixed the problem and now it seems to be working. I also had to fix the next page issue and it seems to be running... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just use Scrapy, there is no way to get the js dynamically generated page. You only get the source code of the webpage.I think you can use Scapy-Splash.